# Printing current when using sinus voltage source?

Tags: ngspice

I am very new to ngscpie, and I need a simple example of very simple circuit composed of two components, a resistor connected to voltage source of sinus wave via two wires.

then to print or plot current applied on the resistor and see the sinus wave, where resistor is one ohm, and voltage source of 1.5 voltage.

Kindly see attached snap-shot, how would I write this simple circuit and print current at R ?

I tried with this circuit:

```
V1 0 1 SIN(0 0.75 60 0 0)
R1 3 4 1
Rwire1 6 2 0.00001
Rwire2 7 1 0.00001
VV1 0 2 dc 0 
VR1 3 5 dc 0 
VRwire1 5 6 dc 0 
VRwire2 4 7 dc 0 
.tran 10ns 400ns 300ns
.print tran i(VV1) i(VR1) i(VRwire1) i(VRwire2) 
.print dc i(VV1) i(VR1) i(VRwire1) i(VRwire2) 
.end
```

which is like this:

[image]

I used VR1 to get current value for R1, what I expect is values between -0.75 and 0.75, as I am using sinus voltage source of 1.5v

however, what I get for VR1 is almost zero:

```
"VR1" => [-6.66155e-5, -6.66406e-5, -6.66658e-5, -6.66909e-5, -6.6716e-5,
   -6.67412e-5, -6.67663e-5, -6.67914e-5, -6.68166e-5, -6.68417e-5, -6.68668e-5,
   -6.6892e-5, -6.69171e-5, -6.69422e-5, -6.69674e-5, -6.69925e-5, -6.70176e-5,
   -6.70428e-5, -6.70679e-5, -6.7093e-5, -6.71182e-5, -6.71433e-5, -6.71684e-5,
   -6.71936e-5, -6.72187e-5, -6.72438e-5, -6.72689e-5, -6.72941e-5, -6.73192e-5,
   -6.73443e-5, -6.73695e-5, -6.73946e-5, -6.74197e-5, -6.74449e-5, -6.747e-5,
   -6.74951e-5, -6.75203e-5, -6.75454e-5, -6.75705e-5, -6.75957e-5, -6.76208e-5,
   -6.76459e-5, -6.76711e-5, -6.76962e-5, -6.77213e-5, -6.77465e-5, -6.77716e-5,
   -6.77967e-5, -6.78219e-5, ...],
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**
I’ve double checked the file, I used `V1 0 1 SIN(0 0.75 60 0 0)` and here is the output:

```
"VR1" => [-5.70678e-5, -5.76332e-5, -5.81987e-5, -5.87642e-5, -5.93297e-5,
   -5.98952e-5, -6.04606e-5, -6.10261e-5, -6.15916e-5, -6.21571e-5, -6.27225e-5,
   -6.3288e-5, -6.38535e-5, -6.4419e-5, -6.49844e-5, -6.55499e-5, -6.61154e-5,
   -6.66809e-5, -6.72463e-5, -6.78118e-5, -6.83773e-5, -6.89428e-5, -6.95082e-5,
   -7.00737e-5, -7.06392e-5, -7.12047e-5, -7.17701e-5, -7.23356e-5, -7.29011e-5,
   -7.34666e-5, -7.4032e-5, -7.45975e-5, -7.5163e-5, -7.57285e-5, -7.62939e-5,
   -7.68594e-5, -7.74249e-5, -7.79904e-5, -7.85558e-5, -7.91213e-5, -7.96868e-5,
   -8.02523e-5, -8.08177e-5, -8.13832e-5, -8.19487e-5, -8.25142e-5, -8.30796e-5,
   -8.36451e-5, -8.42106e-5, ...]
```

I am sorry it seems that the previous output was for different sinus input, I will try change the `.tran` and show output here

**EDIT2**
With `V1 0 1 SIN(0 0.75 60 0 0)` and `.tran 20ms 1s 0ns` I expected to get 50 readings, starting from 0 to 1second, jumping 20ms for each step, but I got only 5 readings:

```
“VR1" => [0.7470853, 0.2935244, -0.565677, 3.233746e-14]
```

Comment: Try to learn this  https://tinyurl.com/y6awrqf5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> V1 0 1 SIN(0 0.75 60 0 0)

This is a sinusoidal source with amplitude 0.75 V and period ~16.7 ms.

> .tran 10ns 400ns 300ns

This says simulate the time window from 0.0003 to 0.0004 ms in 0.00001 ms steps.

So your voltage source has the equation

$$V(t) = (0.75\ {\rm V})\sin\left(2\pi 60 t\right)$$

What is the maximum value of this source in the window you're simulating?

$$(0.75\ {\rm V})\ \sin\left(2\pi 60 [400\times 10^{-9}]\right)=1.97\times 10^{-6}\ {\rm V}$$

With 2 uV applied to your resistor, you shouldn't expect to see much current through it.

The real mystery is why you were seeing ~60 uA instead of the ~2 uA I would have expected. Are you sure the input file you shared is exactly the one used to produce the results you included in your post?

> what I expect is values between -0.75 and 0.75,

To see this you need to simulate over the whole ~17 ms period of the source, not just a tiny 100 ns time window.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, please check edit above

Comment: please see EDIT2 as well..

Comment: Can you please explain the part [ 400 x 10 power -9] ?

Comment: @simo, 1 ns is \$10^{-9}\$ s. 400 ns is \$400\times 10^{-9}\ {\rm s}\$.

Comment: So, it's the end time?

Comment: Yes, the end time is the time in your time window when the sine wave will have its maximum value. Try just plotting the voltage source's voltage to get a clear idea what voltage you're applying to your resistor.

Comment: Thanks, what about only 5 readings I got as per Edit 2 above ?

Comment: @simo, Now you are only sampling the current every 20 ms, which is more than one period of your sinusoid. Try sampling every 1 ms or every 0.1 ms to get a good view of what happens over the sinusoid period.

Comment: But how would I explicitly generate the number of iterations? I devided 1second over 20m, equals 50, we it's bigger than sinus period?

Comment: @simo, I don't know why you got 5 samples instead of 50. But if you make the time step longer than the period, you will get [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Sampling_sinusoidal_functions), which will make it difficult to interpret the results.

Comment: Thanks @The Photon for your help :)